# Excel 2010 VBA & ActiveX functions not responding

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I've got an Excel 2010 file with a bunch of ActiveX controls like VBA buttons and text boxes, but none of them are responding. They had previously worked but the last few times I've opened the file, none of the buttons have worked when I click them and the properties have disappeared. I tried to just create new controls and give them the same properties but an error comes up saying that it cannot insert any objects. Any ideas as to fixing this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could this be your issue?:

[Control Issues](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx)